# Show submit when checkbox is checked loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, checkbox

I've got a page in wordpress that displays around 20 poll questions (using WP-polls).

I'm using a snippet to display the submit button for each poll once an answer has been checked. Thing is, with this snippet I have to copy paste it about 20 times, because of that I some kind of loop.

This is the current code I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $submit = $("#btn-7").hide(),
    $cbs = $('input[name="poll_7"]').click(function() {
        $submit.toggle( $cbs.is(":checked") );
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {

var $submit = $("#btn-6").hide(),
    $cbs = $('input[name="poll_6"]').click(function() {
        $submit.toggle( $cbs.is(":checked") );
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {

var $submit = $("#btn-5").hide(),
    $cbs = $('input[name="poll_5"]').click(function() {
        $submit.toggle( $cbs.is(":checked") );
    });

});
```

As you can see what changes is the "btn_number" ID and "poll_number". This goes on for another 20 snippets. How can I make this dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery allows you to use wildcards, for example:

```
var $submit = $("#btn-*").hide(),
    $cbs = $('input[name="poll_*"]').click(function() {
        $submit.toggle( $cbs.is(":checked") );
    });
```

Edit: I see the wildcard selectors isn't supported by jquery anymore (as above example) you might want to look at: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/ which gives you the ability to use regex to define the selectors for all btn's and code for it once

Comment: @Abhijeetyadav jQuery selectors allows you to add code to multiple buttons without expensive loops or duplicating code. So yes it is effecient. I use it to add the same code functionality to multiple buttons when required

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector on the ID and name attributes, to dynamically access the number. The `change` event is more appropriate than the click event for checkboxes.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8nuqbatq/)**

```
$('[id^="btn-"]').hide();

$('input[name^="poll_"]').change(function(){
    var number = this.name.replace('poll_', '');
    $('#btn-' + number).toggle( $(this).is(":checked") );
});
```

It would be better to use `data-*` attributes to link the buttons and checkboxes, or nest them in an element that has the ID. Parsing the number out of the ID attribute isn't the cleanest way.

Comment: This work just like a charm! Replaced 20 snippets with this little one : ) THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to repeat the same code for 20 times just for getting different button ids. you can make it dynamic. checkout this simple example

```js
$("#submit").click(

   function()
    {
       
              for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
              {
                msg = $("#btn-"+i).val()
                
                alert(msg)
              }
    
    
    }


)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn-1" value="button1"> 
    <input type="button" id="btn-2" value="button2"> 
        <input type="button" id="btn-3" value="button3"> 
            <input type="button" id="btn-4" value="button4"> 
                <input type="button" id="btn-5" value="button5"> 
  
                    <p>
 <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    for(var i=1;i<=20;i++){
        var submit = $("#btn-"+i).hide(),
            cbs    = $('input[name="poll_'+i+'"]').click(function(){
                        submit.toggle($this.is(":checked"));
                     });
    }

});
```